# Angular: strange behavior with ngCookies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, angularjs-scope

In my Angular app

```
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngCookies']);
```

I've defined `authCtrl` controller:

```
mainApp.controller('authCtrl', ['$scope, $cookies',function ($scope, $http, $cookies) {

    $scope.credentials = {};

    $scope.signCheck = function () {
        a = $cookies.getObject('session_credentials');
        console.log(a);
    };
}]);
```

If I'm removing `$scope` declaration from array (injection array?)

```
mainApp.controller('authCtrl', ['$cookies',function ($scope, $http, $cookies) {
```

`$scope` becomes undefined. 
If I'm removing `$cookies` — `$cookies` becomes undefined. 
If I keep them both — [$injector unknown provider error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=$scope,%20$cookiesProvider%20%3C-%20$scope,%20$cookies%20%3C-%20authCtrl).

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just be sure that you indicate the services in a correct order in the injector array and the controller function params:

[Angular docs says](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di):

> This is the preferred way to annotate application components. This is
>   how the examples in the documentation are written.
>
> For example:

```
someModule.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'greeter', function($scope, greeter) {
  // ...
}]);
```

> Here we pass an array whose elements consist of a list of strings (the
>   names of the dependencies) followed by the function itself.
>
> When using this type of annotation, take care to keep the annotation
>   array in sync with the parameters in the function declaration.

Perhaps this controller definition will work for you:

```
mainApp.controller('authCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$cookies', function ($scope, $http, $cookies) {

    $scope.credentials = {};

    $scope.signCheck = function () {
        a = $cookies.getObject('session_credentials');
        console.log(a);
    };
}]);
```